# How can i change my dart-sdk on VSCode

Tags: sdk, visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

i have been using flutter recently and i really wanted to use Jaguar for my project. But here is the catch, the flutter sdk brought dart with version 2.0.0-dev-58.0 but jaguar said they need dart sdk with version 2.0.0-dev-65.0

Okay, so i get myself dart with sdk version of 2.1.0-dev.1.0, but my vscode can't seem to recognize that i have installed the sdk.

Any ideas on how to change that?

Answer (score 6):

It's quite easy if you use VSCode:

1. Clone flutter repo to a new folder:

```sh
mkdir ~/flutter_dev
cd ~/flutter_dev
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git .
```

2. Open your workspace preferences and update `dart.flutterSdkPath` setting:

```
"settings": {
  "dart.flutterSdkPath": "/Users/youruser/flutter_dev"
}
```

3. Restart VSCode and you're good to go.

See more info in [Dart Code - Quickly Switching Between SDK Versions](https://dartcode.org/docs/quickly-switching-between-sdk-versions/)

Answer (score 5):

The `Dart Code` plugin has a setting `dart.sdkPath`

> The location of the Dart SDK to use for analyzing and executing code.
>   If blank, Dart Code will attempt to find it from the PATH environment
>   variable. When editing a Flutter project, the version of Dart included
>   in the Flutter SDK is used in preference.

There's also `dart.sdkPaths` which allows quick switching between alternatives.

For Flutter projects, use `dart.flutterSdkPath(s)`

Answer (score 2):

I want to add one more things to @Andrey, you can use [FVM](https://github.com/leoafarias/fvm#fvm) to install as much as you want versions and channels, it's easy to install and manage versions. It hold all versions on your home directory, I think it's easier than managing with Git.